# xfce panel icons shift

Tags: 14.04, xfce, xfce-panel

[image]

After adding some launchers and indicators to my xfce panel - the panel now shows this huge empty space on the right side.

Normally, all these icons would be **aligned to the right** and the center space is used to show which applications are open. This isn't the case anymore - when no apps are open, these icons shift left.

How can I restore the previous behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a separator to the left and check the expand option.

[image]